# Diagonal Matlab

Tags: matlab, diagonal

What is the difference between these two methods to create new matrix  just with the diagonal values.
The first one ran faster but there is any difference in the accuracy?

```
d1=diag(1./diag(A));

d2=inv(diag(diag(A)));
```

Comment: It should not have and difference theoretically, but since inversing a matrix may involve more computations, I think the accuracy would be lower. And of course, prefer the first one :)

Comment: Usually, when you code you generally DONT want to inver any matrix! avoid it as much as possible!

Comment: @AnderBiguri why should i avoid it? because accuracy?

Comment: http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/

Comment: Are you only interested in the inverse of the diagonal, I would say that operation 1 is far superior to the second. Given that finding the diagonal elements is a deterministic process it can be done with minimum complexity. Also `1./vector` is an O(n) process and is thus extremely effective.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that there is a difference between the methods. I would also assume that the operation that gave d1 were faster without testing it. What is happening then?

```
d1=diag(1./diag(A));
```

First you finds the diagonal in A and temporary "store" it in a vector (`ans=diag(A)`). Then you do a elementwise division on the vector (`ans=1./ans`). The result for these operations is a vector which length is the min(n,m) where n is the number of rows in `A` and m is number of columns in `A`. Then you create a new matrix `d1` where the elements in the vector `1./diag(A)` are placed in the diagonal (`d1=diag(ans)`). The rest of the elements are 0.

```
d2=inv(diag(diag(A)));
```

First you find the diagonal elements with `diag(A)`. Then you create a diagonal matrix with `diag(ans)`. Thirdly you invert it.

Now what would you think happen in case 2 if one diagonal element is 0? Compare the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

There are some differences,

```
A =  [  0     0 ;
      -Inf  -Inf];

d1=diag(1./diag(A))

Inf     0
  0     0

d2=inv(diag(diag(A)))

Inf   Inf
Inf   Inf
```